# Mamp: Wordpress site can't be reached but dashboard can

Tags: wordpress, localhost, mamp, server-error

I'm developing a WordPress site and I'm using Mamp as a local server on a Windows10 machine. I was working on the site when suddenly I couldn't open localhost/mysite anymore. localhost/mysite/wp-admin works just fine and I can use the dashboard but can't access the actual site. I get this error: "This site can't be reached". Any suggestions on how can I solve it? Thanks a lot!
[image]

Comment: First try to Restarting  MAMP and see if the problem is still exits ...

Comment: Disable all the plugin by renaming plugin folder and enable plugins one by one.

Comment: It was a plugin.... Thanks for the help! :)